¿Cómo poder optimizar la consulta sql?
Que tenga un buen día.
Tengo la siguiente query que me demora bastante tiempo en ejecutar:
SELECT
    formapago.codigos,
    formapago.cuentacte AS cargos,
    IFNULL(
        (SELECT SUM(IF(referencias.tipodoc IN (00,61),
                        referencias.valor,
                        referencias.valor*-1
                        ) - IFNULL((SELECT SUM(IF(ref.tipodoc IN (56),ref.valor,ref.valor*-1)) 
                                                        FROM referencias ref 
                                                        WHERE ref.empresa IN(SELECT codigo 
                                                                            FROM intituciones 
                                                                            WHERE codigos = 76291019) 
                                                        AND ref.codigos = referencias.codigos 
                                                        AND ref.tipodoc IN(56,61) 
                                                        AND ref.tipodocref = referencias.tipodoc 
                                                        AND ref.numerodocref = referencias.numerodoc),0)) 
        FROM referencias 
        WHERE referencias.empresa IN (SELECT codigo 
                                        FROM intituciones 
                                        WHERE codigos = 76291019) 
        AND referencias.codigos = formapago.codigos 
        AND referencias.tipodoc IN(00,56,61) 
        AND referencias.tipodocref = formapago.tipodoc 
        AND referencias.numerodocref = formapago.numerodoc),0) AS abonos 
FROM formapago 
LEFT JOIN condicionesp ON IF(formapago.condiciondep=0,1,formapago.condiciondep)=condicionesp.codigo 
LEFT JOIN clientes ON formapago.codigos = clientes.codigos 
WHERE formapago.empresa = 2 
AND formapago.codigos = 77155568 
AND formapago.tipodoc IN (33,34,35,39) 
AND formapago.cuentacte <> 0 
HAVING cargos<>abonos

Nesitaba saber si existe la posibilidad de optimizar la query, quizás cambiar alguna forma de obtner las subquerys podría ser.
Se agradece cualquier ayuda,
Saludos y gracias por su atención.

Partiendo por lo obvio, hay demasiadas subconsultas. Por que no eliminar un par? específicamente (SELECT codigo FROM intituciones WHERE codigos = 76291019. Esta consulta está 2 veces dentro de la consulta, podrian deshacerse de ella, o realizar primero esa consulta y guardar los resultados, pero que no tenga que hacerla 2 veces dentro de la misma query. La otra es AND referencias.tipodoc IN(00,56,61), la cual está casi igual 2 veces, pero una incluye "00", por lo que puede que sea diferente.

¿Por qué lo preguntas? ¿Tarda mucho en ejecutarse? Lo único raro que veo es esa subconsulta en el IFNULL() que se estaría ejecutando en cada fila de la consulta principal y tal vez fuera mejor ejecutarla una única vez y combinarla o incluso almacenarla en una tabla temporal. Pero, sin cronómetro, es complicado aventurarse... Prueba a quitarla a ver cuánto mejoran los tiempos y, si afecta mucho, ya vemos cómo soslayar esa dificultad

@Excorpion, gracias por tu respuesta, como podría trasnformarla,si puedes dar un ejemplo por favor. Gracias

@DavidJP, si es verdad, tarda mucho necesito esas subquery para obtener el resultado esperado, pero si lo transformo en un un inner join, quizas sería mas rapido, no se si me resulta, si tienen un ejemplo, se lo agradecería.

@Danilo No eres nuevo en el sitio y sabes que esto no va así: el que busca el Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable eres tú, no nosotros. Pásanos un dataset con unos datos de ejemplo y te ayudamos a resolverlo.

Podrías compartir datos de prueba? Creo que hay formas de reducir el número de subconsultas pero sin datos de prueba es complicado estar seguro.

Lo primero que me llama la atención son los left outer joins:
LEFT JOIN clientes ON formapago.codigos = clientes.codigos 

¿Códigos? Ojalá no tengas varios códigos en un solo campo. ¿Y qué código? Si un formapago se refiere a un cliente, debería ser algo como formapago.id_cliente = clientes.id_cliente. ¿O hay otros códigos/IDs en esta columna? Esto sería una mala idea en mi opinión.
LEFT JOIN condicionesp ON IF(formapago.condiciondep=0,1,formapago.condiciondep)=condicionesp.codigo 

¿Una condiciondep 0 es una condiciondep 1 en realidad? Por qué no es condiciondep 1 en la table, entonces? Condiciones en ON pueden hacer lento una consulta.
Y por fin, no uses las tablas en tu consulta. Entonces, remueva estos joins.
Entonces, todo se trata de formapagos de un codigo (77155568) y de una empresa (2). Para acceder a los datos rápidamente, hay que tener un index. Por ejemplo:
create index idx1 on formapago(codigos, empresa, tipodoc, cuentacte)

En tu subconsulta buscas referencias. Otra vez, tenemos algunos códigos, y eso hace difícil entender la consulta, o más preciso tu base de datos. Hay instituciones, ¿y estos instituciones son parte de empresas? ¿Y una institución tiene un código que se llama códigos (plural) que debe ser 76291019, y otro código que se llama código (singular) que en realidad es la empresa (el nombre o un ID o algún numero)? Sería mejor si el nombre de la columna en referencia sería id_empresa o nombre_empresa o algo semejante que describe que es. Y si una institución es parte de una empresa, debería tener una columna que se llama id_empresa por ejemplo. Bueno, referencias.empresa IN (...) sugiere que pueden ser más de una empresa.
referencias.codigos = formapago.codigos es difícil de entender también. ¿Una referencia pertenece a un formapago y el código es la ID del formapago? ¿O un formapago pertenece a una referencia y el código es la ID de la referencia? Realmente es muy mala ese de códigos. Bueno, queremos encontrar la referencia rápidamente. Necesitamos un index. Probablemente algo como
create index idx2 on referencias(codigos, numerodocref, tipodocref, tipodoc, empresa)

Y por fin una referencia puede referirse a otra referencia, que vemos en tu sub-subconsulta. Para encontrar esas sub-referencias podemos usar el mismo index, porque usas las mismas columnas para encontrarlas.
Esto es todo. Crea los dos indexes (que deben empezar con una columna muy selectiva - espero que los códigos son bastantes selectivos, es decir hay pocas filas por un código).
Sería buena cosa alterar la base de datos así que las columnas tengan nombres mejores. Las tablas tambíen. A veces usas el singular (formapago) y a veces al plural (clientes). Sé consistente.
Quizás sería posible de mejorar la base de datos aún más (una "referencia" que refiere a una "referencia" suena muy genérico, y estructuras genéricas suelen resultar en consultas lentas en una base de datos).
